How to hide virtual keyboard for Windows
I'm developing a Windows app with MAUI for Windows Surface tablets. I have entries that must not show soft keyboard at all. I tried all the options from this post Need a way to hide soft keyboard in MAUI's Editor / Entry fields
but the only working solution(set control as disabled, then enabled) makes controls unusable(control can't receive focus). Is there any other way to disable soft keyboard for a page or a specific Entry?
I use .NET 8.

Have you tried KeyboardExtensions?

Yes, but keyboard appears after any event I can hook it to, so it's useless, since I hide keyboard before event and after event it appears again. If there is any event after click or focus then it'll work, but I couldn't find the correct one.

Make your focus handler async and add await Task.Delay(100); then you close the keyboard.

If you want to hide the soft input keyboard,you can use entry.HideSoftInputAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None),refer to entry.But, I test the windows platform,the Entry control does not show the soft keyboard.
